# How do you change the value of a getter method that is within an entity?

Tags: java, class, arraylist

I'm trying to incriment the value of a number by 1.

```
public void move(){
    for (Entity e:entities){ 
           e.getX()+1;
      }
```

Comment: I think what you really want to do is use a setter method. Pseudo code would be something like `e.setX(e.getX()+1)`

Comment: Java is *pass-by-value*. When you use a getter method (accessors), only the value is returned, not the actual variable. You cannot modify a variable through a getter; it's the reason a lot of people use them. This is why we have [setters](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method) (mutators)

Answer (score 2):

You need to defined a setter in your `Entity` class.

```
public void setX(int x)
{
    this.x = x;
}
```

Then you can do

```
public void move()
{
    for(Entity e:entities)
        e.setX(e.getX() + 1);
}
```

You can't mutate the value from the getter directly, as it return the value but not the reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change a property that way. You must use a setter:

```
public void move() {
  for (Entity e: entities){
    e.setX(e.getX()+1);
  }
}
```